# Xcode UI test button not tapping

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface

Hi I'm new to UI testing and swift.

What I'm trying to do is just tap the ["+"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDs1p.png) button in the right top corner and then tap on the ["first option"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqIbt.png) that shows up. Xcode says my test is successful, but neither of my taps do anything. Here's my code

```
func test1() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let addButtonButton = app.navigationBars["Timesheets"].buttons["add button"]
    waitForElementToHittable(addButtonButton)
    addButtonButton.tap()

    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    tablesQuery.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).forceTap()
}
```

here's the definition for waitForElementToHittable() and forceTap()

```
 func waitForElementToHittable(element: XCUIElement,
                            file: String = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "hittable == true")
    expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate,
                            evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30) { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            let message = "Failed to hit \(element) after 30 seconds."
            self.recordFailureWithDescription(message,
                                              inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
        }
    }
}

extension XCUIElement {
    func forceTap() {
        if self.hittable {
            self.tap()
        } else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate =     self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You did forget to launch the app:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch() // missing in your code
```